# PHP (двумерный массив) выводить только по одному ключу второго уровня

Tags: php, json, динамические-массивы

Добрый день,

Предположим, есть массив

```
$return[$c]['eventId'] = $data;
$return[$c]['name'] = $data;
$return[$c]['date'] = $data;
$return[$c]['displayDate'] = $data;
$return[$c]['venueName'] = $data;
```

где $c целочисленное, элементов может быть много.

Необходимо формировать json массив состояший только из элементов 
$return[$c]['name'].

Что бы сформировать json массив $return (всех элементов), достаточно использовать json_encode($return);

Вопрос: Можно ли сформировать json массив состоящий только из элементов name во втором уровне, не прибегая к использованию цикла?

Возможно можно отсеять все элементы кроме $return[$c]['name'] перед формированием json (без цикла)?

Спасибо!

Comment: Конечно можно. Поизучайте функции для работы с массивами, в частности [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php).

Answer (score 2):

> Вопрос: Можно ли сформировать json массив состоящий только из элементов name во втором уровне, не прибегая к использованию цикла?

**Нельзя.**

Нужно всегда стараться понимать, как работает код, который мы пишем. Даже тот, которого мы не видим.
Чтобы получить информацию из массива, **цикл нужен всегда.** Даже если написать некую функцию, и потом вызывать её - **цикл от этого никуда не денется.** Он просто будет спрятан внутри функции.

Поэтому циклов бояться не надо.

- Во-первых, потому что цикла все равно не избежать.
- Во-вторых, потому что в циклах в принципе нет ничего такого, ради чего их следовало бы избегать. Если циал слишком долго обрабатывает большой объем данных, то виноват, очевидно, не цикл, а программист, который заранее не ограничил выборку разумным объемом данных.
- В-третьих, если хочется сократить код, то делать это надо с умом. Никогда не надо стремиться к написанию write-only кода, когда ради сокращения одной строчки пишется какой-нибудь array_map() с тремя загибами. Если цикл небольшой, то нет никакой проблемы оставить его в коде - тот, кто будет читать код, скажет потом "спасибо". Если код в цикле сложный, а хочется сократить его - напиши функцию, с четко понятным названием, и помести цикл в неё.

То есть надо четко понимать, что любая однострочная функция, реализующая запрошенный функционал, является всего лишь *синтаксическим сахаром*, скрывая внутри все тот же цикл. поэтому примнеять такие функции следует только по назначению, когда из названия и описания четко ясен возвращаемый результат.

В данном случае такой функцией является [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$names = array_column($return, 'name');
```

следует помнить, что такая функция появилась только в версии 5.5.0